# Add custom HTML via functions.php of theme

Tags: wordpress, validation, accessibility

I'm trying to **add a 'value' attribute to a button in my navbar** in order to pass the WAVE Web Accessibility errors.
However, there is no way for me to access it (I'm using KeyDesign addon with LeadEngine theme).

I had a similar problem with another element, and I fixed it via functions.php.

```
 // [ACCESSIBILITY FIX]: Aria menus fix
 function fix_nav_aria_menus($nav_menu) {
    $modified_nav_menu = str_replace('<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">', '<ul class=" dropdown-menu">', $nav_menu);
    return $modified_nav_menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'fix_nav_aria_menus');
```

Trying to do the same, I unfortunately don't have access to the button I want to change since 'wp_nav_menu' returns an element that is a bit more nested in the navbar.

This is the button that I want to add the attribute 'value' to.
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how to do it in WP, but the button you have highlighted looks like it has an icon for the button image and the button itself does not have any text. What you need is an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) on the button, `<button aria-label="purpose of button">`.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm *commenting* instead of *answering*, because I am providing hints to get you to the correct answer and you specifically said **"Any help is appreciated"**. Apparently not. I would also suggest you read "[Respond to feedback after posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", "[Always be polite and have fun](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)", and "[Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)". Specifying a `value` on the <button> will not fix the problem. `value` is for form submission. `aria-label` or other AccessibleName attributes will work

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)